# Add/Edit/Move Custom TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit, nsmutablearray

**.h

```
IBOutlet UITableView *Table;
NSMutableArray *Currency;
NSArray *Datacell;
```

** Create Custom array

```
Custom *usd = [Custom new];
usd.name = @"USD";
usd.detail = @"United States Dollar";
usd.imageFile = @"usd.jpg";


Custom *eur = [Custom new];
eur.name = @"EUR";
eur.detail = @"Euro Member Countries";
eur.imageFile = @"eur.jpg";

Custom *aud = [Custom new];
aud.name = @"AUD";
aud.detail = @"Australia Dollar";
aud.imageFile = @"AUD.jpg";
Currency = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:usd,eur,aud, nil];
```

Override to support editing the table view.**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
// Delete the row from the data source

     [Currency removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [Table reloadData];
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 }
 else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
 // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
 }
 }
```

**Crash:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x682a0c0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the array currency is not having an element pointed by [Currency removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

You have defined currency as NSMutableArray and inited with Currency = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:usd,eur,aud, nil];

Make it [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:usd,eur,aud, nil];

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the `Currency` object as a `NSArray`

Replace

`Currency = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:usd,eur,aud, nil];`

with

```
Currency = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
[Currency addObject:usd];
[Currency addObject:eur];
[Currency addObject:aud];
```